# Finding complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following question:

Construct a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ whose poles are simple poles at Gaussian integers with residue $1$.

I first took $f(z)=\sum\limits_{u\in \mathbb{Z}(i)}\frac{1}{z-u}$ but this is a divergent series. Then, I took $f(z)=\sum\limits_{u\in \mathbb{Z}(i)}\frac{1}{z-u}+\frac{1}{u}$ but since $u$ is a Gaussian integer, I couldn't say this series is telescoping and converging. So, I am not sure if it diverges but this is my intuition. So, I took, from Taylor series expansion of $f$ at $0$, $f(z)=\sum\limits_{u\in \mathbb{Z}(i)}\frac{1}{z-u}+\frac{1}{u}+\frac{z}{u^2}$ and I guess this series is convergent.

Is this correct or am I wrong somewhere? Thanks in advance.

Comment: since you can construct entire $g$ of order $2$ with the Gaussian integers as simple roots (they are roughly $N^2$ within radius $N$, so $g$ has order $2$) and take $f=g'/g$ you are good as your extra terms are precisely the ones coming from the corresponding Weierstrass factors - another idea is to group them $\pm a \pm ib, a^2+b^2 \le N^2$

Comment: When I do that I get the first function I wrote but it is not convergent that is why I am having problem.

Comment: The Hadamard product is of order $2$ not $1$ like for integers (and essentially $\sin$) so the exponential part of the Weierstrass factors is $e(u)=\exp(z/u+z^2/(2u^2))$ and $e'(u)/e(u)=1/u+z/u^2$ and that is what you need to add to $1/(z-u)$ to get convergence