# Construct a meromorphic function on the complex plane whose poles are simple poles at the Gaussian integers $m+ n\iota$ with residue $1$.

Tags: complex-numbers, analytic-functions, mittag-leffler-function

We know that on summing up all $ \frac{1}{z-(m+n\iota)} $ will not help as $\sum_{m,n\in\Bbb Z} \frac{1}{z-(m+n\iota)} $ is a divergent series. I think some sort of trick is to be used like done in Mittag-Leffler's theorem. If you have any other solution, please write.

This ([Finding complex function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3681983/finding-complex-function)) is the duplicate of the question but there is no answer to this question. Even I read comments, but they were using some *Hadamard Product* and *Weierstrass Factor* which I am completely unaware of.

Thanks!

Comment: look at Weierstrass zeta function

Comment: @user8268 How to prove that the function has simple pole and residue 1? I tried but didn't get any clue to do it.

Comment: Weierstrass zeta is basically the divergent series you suggested, just with some modifying terms which make it absolutely convergent, and that series makes simple poles and residues 1 obvious